# C++ Simple Game Beeping Utility

Tags: c++, game, console, windows, pthreads

Lately I have been playing a game called Dirty Bomb. I like it very much, and since I was taking a rest of basic C++ OpenGL, i tried to make a simple console utility for it.

What i wanted to achieve is that, when I pressed a key (representing an in-game character) the program would, after a specified delay depending on the key pressed, emit a distinct beeping. So when I see an enemy in-game character use its ability, I would press a key, and then after the cooldown delay of its ability is over(or at least near to get over), I get notified with a beeping, so i know if its a danger to get near him. I also wanted to have a "substracted delay" variable, so I could get notified a little before the enemy's ability is ready.

I wanted to have a review in the code I made, since I'm still a newbie in the world of C++ I want to know if there are ways to improve it and, if you're able, ask some questions I commented in there.

Also I've used pthreads for the beeping and waiting parts, since Beep() sleeps its calling thread and waiting can be easily done with the sleep_for() function.

Here is the code, I've commented each part so you know what each does easily:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>    // Question: I'm only using GetAsyncKeyState and Beep functions from windows.h,
                        //           Is there a way so i don't have to include the whole windows header
                        //           and just the ones that have those functions?
#include <thread>  // for multithreading :D
#include <chrono>
#include "notes.h" // An util header i wrote to convert music notes to Hertz, so Beep() can actually play something

using namespace std;

// Holders to know which keys are and were pressed. ( so i can handle Pushing, Holding and Releasing keys ( but i just needed pushing, so :P ) )
bool lastAsyncKeyState[ 0xFF ] = {0};
bool asyncKeyState[ 0xFF ] = {0};

// Functions to save the keyboard state every cicle, so the below function can work
void saveAsyncKeyStates() { for ( int i = 0; i < 0xFF; i++ ) lastAsyncKeyState[i] = asyncKeyState[i]; }
void updateAsyncKeyStates() { for ( int i = 0; i < 0xFF; i++ ) asyncKeyState[i] = ( GetAsyncKeyState(i) ); }

// Only detect if a key was Pushed and not if it's being pressed constantly
bool asyncKeyPushed( int key ) {
    if ( asyncKeyState[key] && !lastAsyncKeyState[key] ) return true;
    return false;
}

const int updatePeriod = 10; // Delay between program updates in milliseconds
const int beepDelay = 1000;  // Delay between beeps when this program is ON
int beepCount = 0;           // counter for ON beeps
int substractDelay = 5;      // How many seconds should the program substract to the original Characters delay
int noteDuration = 200;      // Base note duration

bool shouldUpdateConsole = true; // variable to update the console only when needed
bool onSwitch = false;       // Program state ( ON/OFF )

// Enums for sound types and delays
enum SoundType {
    FRAGGER,
    JAVELIN,
    STOKER,
    SKYHAMMER,
    ONSWITCH,
    OFFSWITCH,
    ON_BEEP
};

enum Delays {
    FRAGGER_DELAY = 20,
    JAVELIN_DELAY = 30,
    STOKER_DELAY = 40,
    SKYHAMMER_DELAY = 70
};


void updateConsole() // Does what it says
{
    system("CLS"); // I know its evil, but I had no other option

    cout << endl;
    cout << "  Substracted Delay: " << substractDelay << endl << endl;
    cout << "    [ T ] Wait for FRAGGER   ( " << Delays::FRAGGER_DELAY - substractDelay << "s )" << endl;
    cout << "    [ G ] Wait for JAVELIN   ( " << Delays::JAVELIN_DELAY - substractDelay << "s )" << "  [ H ] Wait for SKYHAMMER ( " << Delays::SKYHAMMER_DELAY - substractDelay << "s )" << endl;
    cout << "    [ B ] Wait for STOKER    ( " << Delays::STOKER_DELAY - substractDelay << "s )" << endl << endl;
    cout << "  State: " << ( onSwitch ? "ON" : "OFF" ) << endl << endl;
    cout << "    Press [END] to exit." << endl;

    shouldUpdateConsole = false;
}

// Note types
void playSound( int soundType ) {
    switch( soundType ) {
        case SoundType::FRAGGER :
            Beep( noteHz(Note::A + 6*octave), noteDuration/2 );
            Beep( noteHz(Note::A + 6*octave), noteDuration );
            break;
        case SoundType::JAVELIN :
            Beep( noteHz(Note::A + 5*octave), noteDuration/2 );
            Beep( noteHz(Note::B + 5*octave), noteDuration );
            break;
        case SoundType::STOKER :
            Beep( noteHz(Note::G + 5*octave), noteDuration/2 );
            Beep( noteHz(Note::A + 5*octave), noteDuration/2 );
            Beep( noteHz(Note::F + 5*octave), noteDuration );
            break;
        case SoundType::SKYHAMMER :
            Beep( noteHz(Note::G + 5*octave), noteDuration/2 );
            Beep( noteHz(Note::A + 5*octave), noteDuration/2 );
            Beep( noteHz(Note::G + 5*octave), noteDuration/2 );
            Beep( noteHz(Note::A + 5*octave), noteDuration );
            break;
        case SoundType::ONSWITCH :
            Beep( noteHz(Note::A + 7*octave), noteDuration/2 );
            Beep( noteHz(Note::B + 7*octave), noteDuration/2 );
            break;
        case SoundType::OFFSWITCH :
            Beep( noteHz(Note::A + 4*octave), noteDuration/2 );
            Beep( noteHz(Note::G + 4*octave), noteDuration/2 );
            break;
        case SoundType::ON_BEEP :
            Beep( noteHz(Note::C + 4*octave), noteDuration/4 );
            break;
    }
}

// Makes the current thread to wait the specified delay and then play the specified Sound
void waitForAndPlaySound( int seconds, int soundType ) {
    if ( seconds > 0 ) this_thread::sleep_for( chrono::seconds( seconds ) );
    playSound( soundType );
}

// Creates a thread that runs waitForAndPlaySound, with the specified sound and delay
void playSoundProtocol( int soundType, int delay ) {
    thread tempThread( waitForAndPlaySound , delay , soundType );
    tempThread.detach(); // Error if not detached.
}

// The main loop :D
int main()
{
    while ( !GetAsyncKeyState(VK_END) ) { // Program will execute until the END key is pressed
        updateAsyncKeyStates(); // Gets the keys that are pressed now, to compare with the keys that were pressed in the last cycle

        if ( asyncKeyPushed( VK_INSERT ) ) { // if the INSERT key is pushed, the program will switch to ON/OFF.
            onSwitch = !onSwitch;
            playSoundProtocol( ( onSwitch ? SoundType::ONSWITCH : SoundType::OFFSWITCH ), 0 );
            shouldUpdateConsole = true;
        }

        if ( asyncKeyPushed( VK_UP ) && substractDelay < 10 ) { substractDelay++; shouldUpdateConsole = true; }  // MAX substracted delay is 10
        if ( asyncKeyPushed( VK_DOWN ) && substractDelay > 0 ) { substractDelay--; shouldUpdateConsole = true; } // MIN substracted delay is 0

        if ( onSwitch ) { // If the program is ON
            if ( asyncKeyPushed( 'T' ) ) // T is to wait for the character Fragger in-game ability
                playSoundProtocol( SoundType::FRAGGER, Delays::FRAGGER_DELAY - substractDelay );
            if ( asyncKeyPushed( 'G' ) ) // G is to wait for the character Javelin in-game ability
                playSoundProtocol( SoundType::JAVELIN, Delays::JAVELIN_DELAY - substractDelay );
            if ( asyncKeyPushed( 'B' ) ) // B is to wait for the character Stoker in-game ability
                playSoundProtocol( SoundType::STOKER, Delays::STOKER_DELAY - substractDelay );
            if ( asyncKeyPushed( 'H' ) ) // H is to wait for the character Skyhammer in-game ability
                playSoundProtocol( SoundType::SKYHAMMER, Delays::SKYHAMMER_DELAY - substractDelay );

            beepCount += updatePeriod;      // The program beeps every beepDelay, so the user knows the program is active (ON).
            if ( beepCount >= beepDelay ) { beepCount -= beepDelay; playSoundProtocol( SoundType::ON_BEEP, 0 ); }

            // Question: is there a way to control the volume of Beep ?

        } else { // If the program is OFF
            if ( beepCount != 0 ) beepCount = 0;
        }

        if ( shouldUpdateConsole ) updateConsole(); // If the console should update, it calls the updateConsole func
        saveAsyncKeyStates(); // Saves the keys that are pressed now, so the next cycle can use them
        this_thread::sleep_for( chrono::milliseconds( updatePeriod ) ); // Sleeps for updatePeriod
    }
    return 0;
}
```

notes.h

```
#ifndef NOTES_H
#define NOTES_H

enum Note{ // Starts from C0
    C = -57, // C starts at -57, so A0 ( -48 ) plus 4 octaves ( 48 ) results in 0, so the noteHz function can work properly.
    Db,
    D,
    Eb,
    E,
    F,
    Gb,
    G,
    Ab,
    A,
    Bb,
    B
};

extern const int octave; // = 12

float noteHz( int );

#endif // NOTES_H
```

notes.cpp

```
#include "notes.h"
#include <cmath>

// Note to Hertz constants and stuff, more info on:
// http://pages.mtu.edu/~suits/NoteFreqCalcs.html

const float a = std::pow( 2.0f , 1.0f/12 ); // Question: if someone can tell me how to make this constant "private"
                                            // so only this .cpp can use it i would thank you :)

const int octave = 12; // Quantity of half notes in an octave ( or the length of the Note enum )

// This function transforms musical notes to Hz.
// It works by setting the center note as A4 ( 440 Hz ), then calculating every other Hz note from that point.
float noteHz( int note ) {
    return 440.0f * std::pow( a , note );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I understand you might have inserted some of the comments only for the sake of this review, but many of them are too verbose and in fact hurt readability. As a C++ programmer, if I see `int main()`, I know that's the main program without a comment, or if I see `#include <thread>` I know what it entails. So prefer comments that answer the question "how" instead of "why". Remember that good code is always self-commenting through proper variable names and so on.
- Avoid writing `using namespace std;`. [See here for more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).
- To answer your question about includes, no, you need to include a header if you need even a single function from it.
- I would make 0xFF a constant instead of using it as a magic number.
- Avoid using non-const global variables. Specifically, you can make `beepCount`, `substractDelay`, `noteDuration`, `shouldUpdateConsole` and `onSwitch` local to the main program. And moreover, is there a reason `noteDuration` can't be const?
- To the previous point, `updateConsole` should take an argument `bool shouldUpdateConsole` so you don't need it to be a global.
- You can use `\n` instead of `std::endl` for line breaks when you don't need to flush the buffer as well. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n).
- To make a constant only visible inside a .cpp, use an unnamed namespace:

  ```
  #include "notes.h"
  #include <cmath>

  namespace 
  {
      const float a = std::pow( 2.0f , 1.0f/12 );
  }

  const int octave = 12;

  float noteHz( int note ) 
  {
      return 440.0f * std::pow( a , note );
  }
  ```